# Fetch Local Content on my Mac to list out in my Application

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have a MAC Desktop application, that need to list all the local music files on one tab and videos on to another tab.

I am not able to fetch the complete music/video data in my hard disk with in a fraction of seconds.

when ever the Application is launched complete data should be fetched and should be loaded in my application.

Any solutions appreciated.....

Comment: Too broad, what do you mean by "fetch the complete music/video data" and what have you tried so far? Please show us the code and is it swift or objective-c you are programming in?

Comment: I am programming in Objective c, and I need a clarification whether can we get local hard disk data either it may be music or vidoes using file systems.

Comment: If you are asking for some 3rd party library that can do that then your question is off-topic for stackoverflow, if not then please clarify what your issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Use CoreSpotlight. It

- uses indexed search and
- does its search in background, so the UI isn't block.

Comment: Do we have CoreSpotlight support for Mac OS X (Objective c)